# VBA: Ignoring Conditional in For-Each Loop

Tags: vba, excel

**Problem Statement**

I have a couple of dependent combo boxes for some countries and states of those countries. I am using VBA to populate unique values in the first combo box and then dynamically populate unique values in the second combo box. The code seems to be ignoring the conditional in the initial pass.

For example the code works for the first country:

[image]

But following countries incorrectly retain the first State value:

[image]

**Data**

This is the data set, with the Names "Country" and "State". These Names correspond dynamically to the range below each heading:

[image]

Name references use formulas in this format:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$2,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A),1)
```

Combo boxes are ActiveX objects with the names "countries" and "states" respectively.

**Code**

Code snippet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
'Populate combo box with unique countries.
  Dim arr() As String
  Dim tmp As String
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
  Me.countries.Clear
  For Each rng In ws.Range("Country")
    If (rng <> "") And (InStr(tmp, rng) = 0) Then
      tmp = tmp & rng & "|"
    End If
  Next rng

  If Len(tmp) > 0 Then tmp = Left(tmp, Len(tmp) - 1)

  arr = Split(tmp, "|")

  Me.countries.List = arr

End Sub

Private Sub countries_lostfocus()
  'Populate dependent combo box with unique states
  'according to selection in countries combo box.
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim str As String
  Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
  str = countries.Value
  Me.states.Clear
  On Error Resume Next
  For Each rng In ws.Range("State")
    If ((rng.Offset(, -1).Value) = str) And (IsNotInArray(rng.Value, Me.states.List)) Then
      Me.states.AddItem rng.Value
    End If
  Next rng
End Sub

Function IsNotInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
  IsNotInArray = IsError(Application.Match(stringToBeFound, arr, 0))
End Function
```

**Miscellaneous**

The NSW state value will be stored in the combo box for all following countries that are added.

Using MsgBox to debug inside the loop as such:

```
  For Each rng In ws.Range("State")
    If ((rng.Offset(, -1).Value) = str) And (IsNotInArray(rng.Value, Me.states.List)) Then
      MsgBox ("Country: " & str & "; check: " & rng.Offset(, -1).Value)
      Me.states.AddItem rng.Value
    End If
  Next rng
```

Seems to show that the first portion of the conditional is failing to operate as expected when selecting a country other than Australia:

[image]

Comment: A `For-Each` loop is not the same thing as a `For Loop`.

Comment: Does your list change?  If it doesn't, I'd use a `Dictionary` of `Country, State` instead of searching it every time the first combo changes.

Comment: Also, consider using a `Collection` instead of concatenating and splitting strings to store lists of values.

Comment: @Dai thanks, I have changed it to For-Each

Comment: @Comintern, unfortunately it does for States in particular. This is also intended to eventually extend to cities which will change more frequently again.

Comment: You wont be able to debug it without removing the `On Error Resume Next`. You're entering the loop following some error.

Comment: @A.S.H Thanks that leads me to the error "Object variable or With Block variable not set". I assume the Me.states.List is empty and could be causing the issue, I will investigate now.

Comment: All I can say is that NSW **should** be included in every list !!!  And you should force the country to always be Australia so that you don't have conflicting information.  ( ;-)  You can tell I am a proud New South Welshman.)

Comment: @YowE3K lol one more such word and we wont help anymore! :P

Comment: So as a hacky workaround I have added an initial vale of "" to the Me.states.List and NSW no longer appears (sorry @YowE3K ), but it now retains the blank value. I am still baffled as to how it passes the first part of the conditional though!

Comment: @vagon it didn't necessarily pass it. Remember VBA does not have the "short-circuiting semantics". both parts of your `If` will be evaluated independently in all cases.

Comment: And when an error occurs in the `If`, the bloc will be entered if you had `on error resume next`. A liitle counter-intuitive but that's how VBA works.

Comment: @A.S.H that helps my understanding, if not exactly making sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have use the same approach as in Country. And why don't you use the `countries_Change` event?

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub countries_Change()
    Dim sCountry As String
    Dim sList As String
    Dim rng As Range
    sCountry = Me.countries.Value
    Me.states.Clear
    With ThisWorkbook.Names("State")
        For Each rng In .RefersToRange
            If Not IsEmpty(rng) Then
                If rng.Offset(0, -1).Value = sCountry Then
                    If InStr(1, sList, rng.Value, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                        If Len(sList) > 0 Then sList = sList & "|"
                        sList = sList & rng.Value
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
    Me.states.List = Split(sList, "|")
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim sList As String
    Dim rng As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Names("Country")
        For Each rng In .RefersToRange
            If Not IsEmpty(rng) Then
                If InStr(1, sList, rng.Value, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                    If Len(sList) > 0 Then sList = sList & "|"
                    sList = sList & rng.Value
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
    Me.countries.List = Split(sList, "|")
    countries_Change ' <-- This is better User experience
End Sub
```

Comment: @vagon Although this is accepted as solution, this is not the efficient method if you have large dataset of Countries and States.

Comment: @vagon - FWIW, be careful with the order of loading countries using this method - for instance, make sure "Guinea" occurs before "Papua New Guinea", and "Samoa" occurs before "American Samoa", or else they won't be loaded.

Comment: Thanks both, that is pragmatic enough to get me by

Answer (score 2):

As much as I don't want to see NSW being left out of any lists, you can fix your problem by testing whether your `arr` variable is empty prior to trying to do a `Match`:

```
Function IsNotInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    If UBound(Arr) = -1 Then
        IsNotInArray = True
    Else
        IsNotInArray = IsError(Application.Match(stringToBeFound, arr, 0))
    End If
End Function
```

If `arr` is passed to that function as the cleared list of a ComboBox, it will have a `LBound` of 0 and an `UBound` of -1, so the test on the `UBound` will prevent the `Match` from crashing.